# Is there a pluralize  function in Ruby NOT Rails?

Tags: ruby, require, pluralize

I am writing some Ruby code, not Rails, and I need to handle something like this:

```
found 1 match
found 2 matches
```

I have Rails installed so maybe I might be able to add a `require` clause at the top of the script, but does anyone know of a RUBY method that pluralizes strings? Is there a class I can require that can deal with this if the script isn't Rails but I have Rails installed?

**Edit:** All of these answers were close but I checked off the one that got it working for me.
Try this method as a helper when writing Ruby, not Rails, code:

```
def pluralize(number, text)
  return text.pluralize if number != 1
  text
end
```

Comment: The edit is not correct. There is no ruby function String#pluralize, you are missing require 'active_support/inflector' or something else.

Comment: Well Rails is always changing. Feel free to edit my question so its correct. I'm not currently working with rails so I don't have the time to test this and see what the correct way to do this is now.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Actually all you need to do is

```
require 'active_support/inflector'
```

and that will extend the String type.

you can then do

```
"MyString".pluralize
```

which will return

```
"MyStrings"
```

---

for 2.3.5 try:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/inflector'
```

should get it, if not try

```
sudo gem install activesupport
```

and then the requires.

Comment: for 2.3.5
    sudo gem install activesupport

    require 'rubygems'
    require 'active_support/inflector'

should get it

I'm using edge rails (3) there's been a lot of decoupling, and it appears to bundle with it by default

Comment: This is the core of ActiveView's pluralize, however ActiveView#pluralize also knows when it should use the plural or singular version, based on the first parameter.

Answer (score 58):

Inflector is overkill for most situations.

```
def x(n, singular, plural=nil)
    if n == 1
        "1 #{singular}"
    elsif plural
        "#{n} #{plural}"
    else
        "#{n} #{singular}s"
    end
end
```

Put this in common.rb, or wherever you like your general utility functions and...

```
require "common" 

puts x(0, 'result') # 0 results
puts x(1, 'result') # 1 result
puts x(2, 'result') # 2 results

puts x(0, 'match', 'matches') # 0 matches
puts x(1, 'match', 'matches') # 1 match 
puts x(2, 'match', 'matches') # 2 matches
```

Comment: This is a really great solution. Simple and really all you will need.

Comment: That does the job perfectly, Great solution indeed.

Answer (score 15):

I personally like the [linguistics gem](http://deveiate.org/projects/Linguistics) that is definitely not rails related.

```
# from it's frontpage
require 'linguistics'

Linguistics.use :en

"box".en.plural #=> "boxes"
"mouse".en.plural #=> "mice"
# etc
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (using ruby 2.1.1 and actionpack 3.2.17):

```
~$ irb
>> require 'action_view'
=> true
>> include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
=> Object
>> pluralize(1, 'cat')
=> "1 cat"
>> pluralize(2, 'cat')
=> "2 cats"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/inflector'

inf = ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections.new
```

to get the inflector, not sure how you use it

Answer (score 1):

my solution:

```
# Custom pluralize - will return text without the number as the default pluralize.
def cpluralize(number, text)
  return text.pluralize if number != 1 
  return text.singularize if number == 1
end
```

So you can have 'review' returned if you call cpluralize(1, 'reviews')

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've defined a helper function for that, I use it for every user editable model's index view :

```
  def ovyka_counter(array, name=nil, plural=nil)
    name ||= array.first.class.human_name.downcase
    pluralize(array.count, name, plural)
  end
```

then you can call it from the view :

```
<% ovyka_counter @posts %>
```

for internationalization (i18n), you may then add this to your locale YAML files :

```
  activerecord:
    models:
      post: "Conversation"
```